# How to HTTPS/POST on iOS in latest Delphi using native calls?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

The latest version of Delphi, XE4, allows for the building of iOS applications. There was some discussions on the newsgroups to use native iOS libraries for HTTPS/Posting to avoid issues with OpenSSL libraries and Indy 10. What's the recommended way of using native libraries to perform HTTP Posting?  (In my example, JSON document upload and response.)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer on this? I'm having issues here as well. I've seen in other environments that Indy 10 is making calls to OpenSSL for SSLv1 and SSLv2 which are no longer supported, commenting out the Indy code for those calls in those environment seemed to do the trick, but it feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

Background:
Indy, the "native" code used for webservice calls in XE4, relies on OpenSSL. In most situations, OpenSSL is linked to via dynamic library (in windows a DLL). iOS does not support dynamic libraries, therefore once the code is compiled into a binary and sent to an iOS device, the OpenSSL calls fail because there is no backing library. The solution is to compile OpenSSL into your project. You can do this by downloading the OpenSSL source and adding it to your project, or source the static libraries from somewhere else and add them to your project. I found the static libraries here:
http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/OpenSSLStaticLibs.7z
That is one of the indy mirrors, so hopefully it should be OK. You need to put the two files somewhere that your project is knowledgeable of and then add IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_Static to your uses. Now, your compiled code will include the OpenSSL code and your issue should be resolved.